# Chaining multiple obj files and make them as a movie

Tags: animation, objects, import

I am trying to using blender to do scientific visualization. Currently, I have the obj files that changing over time (around 250 obj files).

I want to change them in to a movie, so that each frame will have one obj file that showed and the whole movie will have 250 frames.

Anyone know how to do it with blender?

****UPDATE****

The solution with obj files posted in the link is no longer able to work since my version is 6.74. And it only works for 6.62 and the solution script is also removed, so I am not able to work with the solution anymore. It would be nice if someone can provide me the script here.

Comment: You could render the files as pictures and put the results in the movie.

Comment: The problem is I have so many obj files that it is hard to render them all one by one

Comment: I am trying to use some python script however I am not able to add shape keys

Comment: You might also try the Blender add-on Stop Motion OBJ. It supports sequences of .PLY, .OBJ, and .STL files. It also supports geometry with different vertex counts from frame to frame. https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ